# Definition of base has to precede definition of derived contract (ERC721 implementation)

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, erc721

The top [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67385322/definition-of-base-has-to-precede-definition-of-derived-contract) or [ETH Stack Exchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/34618/typeerror-definition-of-base-has-to-precede-definition-of-derived-contract) answers don't seem to apply to my case (I could be wrong of course)

I'm getting the error describer in the title in this file:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./ERC721Metadata.sol";
import "./ERC721.sol";

contract ERC721Connector is ERC721Metadata, ERC721 {
                                         // ^^^^^^^ (Definition of base has to precede definition of derived contract)
    constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol) ERC721Metadata(name, symbol) {}
}
```

Here's what ERC721Metadadata looks like:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract ERC721Metadata {
    string private _name;
    string private _symbol;

    constructor(string memory named, string memory symbolified) {
        _name = named;
        _symbol = symbolified;
    }

    function name() external view returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    function symbol() external view returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }
}
```

And here is what ERC721 looks like:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./ERC721Metadata.sol";
import "./ERC721Connector.sol";

contract ERC721 {
    event Transfer(
        address indexed from,
        address indexed to,
        uint256 indexed tokenId
    );

    mapping(uint256 => address) private _tokenOwner;
    mapping(address => uint256) private _OwnedTokensCount;

    function _exists(uint256 tokenId) internal view returns (bool) {
        address owner = _tokenOwner[tokenId];
        return owner != address(0);
    }

    function _mint(address to, uint256 tokenId) internal {
        require(to != address(0), "ERC721: minting to the zero address");
        require(
            !_exists(tokenId),
            "ERC721: minting a token that already exists (been minted)"
        );
        _tokenOwner[tokenId] = to;
        _OwnedTokensCount[to] += 1;

        emit Transfer(address(0), to, tokenId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to import `ERC721Connector` contract in your `ERC721` contract? If not, you can remove

```
import "./ERC721Connector.sol"; // line 4, ERC721.sol
```

from your file and it should work fine. Your imports are causing the issue,

`ERC721Connector` tries to import `ERC721`, but `ERC721` also needs `ERC721Connector` so the compiler says

> Definition of base has to precede definition of derived contract

Because the base contract doesn't *precede* the defined contract.